# two different liferay non root context in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I want two liferay instance in a single tomcat server. To achieve this I have done the following things.

- Replicated the ROOT folder as app1 and app2 within webapps. The content of app1 and app2 folder is exactly the same as that of liferay ROOT folder.
- Replaced the ROOT folder with a normal tomcat(non-liferay) ROOT content
- Within **apache-tomcat-7.0.65 > conf > Catalina > localhost** Replicated the ROOT.xml as app1.xml and app2.xml and changed. The content of app1.xml and app2.xml is given below
- **app1.xml** - `<Context path="/app1" crossContext="true"> </Context>`
- **app2.xml** - `<Context path="/app2" crossContext="true"> </Context>`

I need the liferay instance to be accessed like as shown below

**app1** on http://localhost:8080/app1
**app2** on http://localhost:8080/app2

When I remove app2, then app1 is working fine and I am able to access the liferay instance using http://localhost:8080/app1.

**apache-tomcat-7.0.65 > webapps**

[image]

**apache-tomcat-7.0.65 > conf > Catalina > localhost**

[image]

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Answer (score 1):

It won't work: Liferay monitors other applications that are deployed to tomcat (that's the `crossContext="true"` in your context.xml) and picks them up: That's the way you deploy plugins to Liferay - and you couldn't target plugins to one or the other Liferay otherwise, or they'd be initialized twice.

If you need two different Liferay installations, you'll need two different tomcats running. You can combine them with the distinction between `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` and make them share the same code base, but have different configurations and deployed webapps.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be enough to have one installation of Liferay portal in a single Tomcat (e.g. standard installation) and use Liferay instances/companies instead? See *Control Panel -> Portal Instances -> Add*. You can also use different address of each instance by setting proper virtual host:

- http://app1.localhost:8080
- http://app2.localhost:8080

Comment: but where we can deploy the two applications. both having different databases

Comment: Applications will be deployd into Lifeary as you are used to (i.e. into deploy folder). You can have different databases and data sources for each application. Another solution would be to have single database and datasource and distinguish application tables with prefix e.g. app1_ and app2_ or you can have different DB schemas for each applications (this depends on DB you are using).